# “name is not defined” inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

I want to create a countdown clock and I almost did but if I run this code down below and press the 'go' button, I get the error:  `NameError: name 'be' is not defined`. Even if I try to put `global be` in there it doesn't seem to work

```
import tkinter as tk
def set1():
    global be
    if be1 is not '':
        be = int(en.get())
    
def countdown():
    global be
    
    if be >= 0:
        mins, secs = divmod(be, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        
        label['text'] = timer
        root.after(1000, countdown)
        be -= 1

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text = '00:00', font = 'Helvetica 25')
label.pack()

en = tk.Entry(root)
en.pack()
be1 = en.get()
tk.Button(root, text = 'set', height = 3, width = 20, command = lambda: set1()).pack()
tk.Button(root, text = 'go', height = 3, width = 20, command = lambda: countdown()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's because you try to compare `be` to 0 before having set a value for it.

Comment: even if I try to press the set button first (So then be is defined) it gives the same error

Comment: You *don't* define ``be`` before using it. What makes you think it should be defined?

Comment: Don't you execute `be1 = en.get()` *before* the user got a chance to enter anything?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille yes but then be1 will be ' ' and that gives an error

Comment: This is the problem I'm pointing to...

Comment: so... I declare be as 0 at the beginning? that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give `be` a value on top of your code, for example

```py
be = 0
```